# isomorphism classes over algebraic closure vs bigger extensions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I found a statement in "A first Course in Modular Forms" Diamond Shurman that essentially said(at the best of my understanding)

> if two complex elliptic curves defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ then they are isomorphic over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.)

I think this can easely be proved using the fact that curves defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ have a rational $j$-invariant and they have an essentialy unique Weierstrass equation.

My question(if what I said is correct) is about some kind of generalization of this fact, can we say that two algebraic varieties defined over a field $K$ are isomorphic over an extension $L$, with $K\subseteq \overline{K}\subseteq L$, if and only if they are isomorphic over $\overline{K}$? If not, what are the restriction we have to make in order to have a true statement, if this is possible at all.

Comment: At least for affine varieties: the pair of morphisms are defined over a finitely generated $K$-algebra $S\subset L$, then you can take a $K$-algebra homomorphism $S\to F\subset \overline{K}$, which gives an homomorphism $S[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^n\to F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^n$ that you can compose with the polynomial map defining the algebraic variety isomorphism over $L$, to get an isomorphism over $F$.

Comment: thanks, if I understood well you can choose any omomorphism from $S$ to $\overline{K}$. Even saying that $S\simeq F[y_1,\dots, y_k]$ with $F\subseteq \overline{K}$ and choosing the valuation in $(0,\dots,0)$

Comment: $0$ doesn't have to work. The isomorphism $V(x_1x_2-1)\to V(x_1x_2-1)$ given by $(x_1,x_2)\to (x_1t,x_2/t)$ is defined over the finitely generated $\Bbb{Q}$-algebra $S=\Bbb{Q}[t,t^{-1}]$. Sending $t$ to any element $a\in\overline{\Bbb{Q}}-0$ gives an homomorphism $S\to \Bbb{Q}(a)$ and the isomorphism $V(x_1x_2-1)\to V(x_1x_2-1)$ given by $(x_1,x_2)\to (x_1a,x_2/a)$

Comment: And how can we prove that we can always find a morphism that works? I was trying to prove that maybe the sets of points for which it works is zariski open or something similar

Comment: It is called [Zariski lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma) $S=K[z_1,\ldots,z_n]/I$ for some proper ideal $I$ and $V(I)$ has a $\overline{K}$ point. Equivalently $S$ has a maximal ideal and $S/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field finitely generated as $K$-algebra so it is a finite extension thereof.